# how to query an object if it has a field with only a specific value in views psql django

Tags: django, view, model, querying

my `models.py` is :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    truck_number = models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    date= models.DateField()
    product=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    depot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    volume_delivered = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    driver_name=models.CharField(max_length=30,default=None)
    driver_id_number=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    driver_phone_number=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

so i need a view which needs to render the whole objects of Table Order  if only the value of  field order_status is Loaded. How do i write this logic in django views.

Comment: You use a `ListView`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

Comment: how specifically do you use ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is two ways, either filter on the ones you want, or exclude the ones you dont want. (note the double underscore for the __in operator)

```
loadings = Object.objects.filter(order_status__in=['Loaded', 'Released', 'Received'])
```

or

```
loadings = Object.objects.exclude(order_status__in=['Failed', 'Error', 'Whatever'])
```

Comment: Then please mark it as an answer else this is listed as unsolved!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by using :

from django.db.models import Q
and then filtering on the views using :

def loading(request):

```
loadings = Order.objects.filter(Q(order_status='Loaded') | Q(order_status='Released') | Q(order_status='Received'))
return render(request, 'loadings.html' ,{'loadings':loadings})
```